# How to get crash from null pointer dereference in every program run?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, null, crash

I compile this code with `Dev C++` as a `32-bit` executable.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
float f,*pf, i;
i = 10;
pf = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float));
pf = &i;

free(pf);
f = *pf;
printf("%f\n", f);

printf("%f", *pf);
}
```

Dereferencing freed pointer cause a crash, here the crash is not happening because of undefined behavior.

I am testing and learning now, I want to write a null pointer dereference code to crash in every program run.How to write my code to get crash in every run?

Comment: the program is already crashing in every run dev c++ version 5.9.2.

Comment: I am using version 5.11 on win 8, May be a cause of compiler optimization?

Comment: may be but as all said there is no defined behaviour for crash.

Comment: **Undefined behaviour** can be anything. It not even does guarantee the code actually does _not_ work. This is actually the worst thing that can happen with UB: you do not notice anything. Just think of a loong document you work on line 4000 and in line 1 changes something. Then save (no backup/svn). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First you allocated memory to `pf` using `malloc` and then assigning the address of `i` to it which leads to memory leak.

```
pf = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float));
pf = &i;        // No reference to previous allocated memory.
```

Then you are applying `free` to `pf` which is not returned by `malloc` family function. This will invoke undefined behavior.
"Undefined" means outcome is not defined. Crash may or may not happen. You can't rely on this.

Also note that freeing a pointer doesn't mean that it will point to `NULL`. It means that the freed memory is available for reallocation.

You can use standard library function `abort` for abnormal program termination.

Comment: There is no *defined* behaviour resulting in crash.

Comment: Can't we force the program to crash because of null pointer dereference? Can't we make a suitable situation for that?

Comment: No. You can't. Use `abort` instead.

Comment: Well, in your case you can try to write into that location. It will probably crash. But not necessarily...

Comment: @EugeneSh. That's worked! but what about just reading from memory?

Comment: @yaAli Again, you just got "lucky" that it crashed. UB is UB for a reason.

Comment: After downvoting a comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The question title and description are wrong. You keep asking about "null pointer dereference", but you are *not* dereferencing a null pointer anywhere. In fact, the pointer you are dereferencing (`pf`) is guaranteed to not be null, since it is the address of the variable `i`.

Your undefined behavior is instead caused by using `free()` on a pointer to something that was not dynamically allocated (`pf` points to the local variable `i`).

Comment: I wrote this and it crashed, so this is the null pointer dereference? `struct book {
 char *name;
 int *price;
} book1;
 

 printf ("%s", book1.name);

 return 0;`

Comment: @yaAli: This is not complete code. Is all of that inside the `main()` function? Or is `book1` defined outside the function? If `book1` is a local variable, it is uninitialized. Its `name` field is uninitialized and can contain any address. It may or may not be null. If `book1` is a global variable, C specifies that variables with static storage (including global variables) are zero-initialized; so that would mean `book1.name` is guaranteed to be a null pointer. If `book1.name` is not null and points to a random place, printing it will very likely crash.

Comment: @yaAli: If `book1.name` is a null pointer, the C standard doesn't specify what `printf` does for `%s` specifier for a null pointer. In GNU libc and some other implementations, `printf` with `%s` and a null pointer is well-defined to put `(null)` into the output.